# Averaging over sub columns of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, average

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
1 4
0 3
0 1
0 3
1 2
0 0
0 6
```

1's in the first column are guaranteed to be > N steps apart.
For each occurrence of 1 in the first column, I want to take a slice of length M (M < N) of the second column and average the results.

E.g. for M = 2, I have two slices: 4,3 and 2,0 so the result should be 2,1.5 (say, as a Series or a list).

Can't come up with anything but manually iterating over the rows. Would be grateful for any suggestions!

EDIT: The example I gave could interpreted in two ways, I changed the numbers, so that's clear: I don't want a list of group averages, but rather for each slice position, the average of corresponding entries over the groups.

Answer (score 1):

use groupby!

```
import pandas as pd

# Example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    'col2': [4, 3, 1, 3, 3, 0, 6]
})

N = 3  # N steps
M = 2  # Length of the slice

# Create a mask for the rows where col1 is 1
mask = df['col1'] == 1

# Group the dataframe by the cumulative sum of the mask
groups = df.loc[mask].groupby(mask.cumsum())

# Calculate the average of each slice of length M in col2
result = groups['col2'].apply(lambda x: x.rolling(M, min_periods=1).mean())

print(result)
```

Comment: Please, see my edit, sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
(df.assign(means = df['col1'].cumsum())
 .groupby('means')['col2']
 .agg(lambda x: x[:2].mean()))
```

Output:

```
means
1    3.5
2    1.5
Name: col2, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `groupy` approach:

```
out = (df.groupby(df['col1'].cumsum())['col2']
         .apply(lambda g: g.head(M).mean())
      )
```

Output:

```
col1
1    3.5
2    1.5
Name: col2, dtype: float64
```

Or an alternative with `cumsum`, slicing of the M's item per group and, division by M to get the mean:

```
g = df.groupby(df['col1'].cumsum())

out = (g['col2'].cumsum()
 .loc[g.cumcount().eq(M-1)]
 .div(M)
)
```

Comment: Please, see my edit, sorry for confusion.

Comment: @LazyCat I believe my code was already working as you expect: getting the mean of the M first values in Col2 for each group starting with a 1 in Col1

Comment: no, I don't think so: I'm not looking for a list of group averages, but rather a list of intergroup averages

Comment: @LazyCat got it, see update (if the website lets me update… running into an error). In the meantime here is the updated command: `out = df.assign(n=df.groupby(df['col1'].cumsum()).cumcount()).query('n < @M').groupby('n')['col2'].mean().tolist()`

Comment: In summary, you first need to compute the position per group, then filter the positions < M, finally aggregate again this time per position to compute the mean.